# Linq OrderBy dependencies on other entities

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have collections of entities that I need to sort depending on their dependencies to each other. Here's an example because it's fairly tough to explain:

```
public class A : I {
    private B objB;
    public B propB { get{ return objB; } }
    // Some other fields and properties.
}

public class B : I { /* Some fields and properties. */ }

public class C : I {
    private A objA;
    public A propA { get{ return objA; } }
    // Some other fields and properties.
}

public interface I {}
```

The thing is that I need to import data into collections of those types but I need to import in a certain order because if I import `A` objects first, I will not be able to link the corresponding `B` since it won't exist yet.

So what I'd like is to sort my collections in a way that all dependencies are imported in the right order **(There are no circular dependencies)**. I can't figure out a linq statement that will do that though.

```
lists.OrderBy(l => l. ??? );
```

I was thinking maybe get a list `typesList` of all the types `T` of the `List<T>` in `lists` and somehow use reflection to count how many fields in `T` are in `typesList` but that seems... inefficient ?

---

EDIT: Realized the wording of my structure is a bit vague.
Basically `lists` is a `List<List<I>>`. Here's a results example:

```
List<List<I>> collections before:
    -List<A>
    -List<C>
    -List<B>

List<List<I>> collections after:
    -List<B>  // B has 0 dependency to B or C.
    -List<A>  // A has 1 dependency to B.
    -List<C>  // C has 1 dependency to A.
```

Comment: will objB be named the same in each class and be of different type?

Comment: You can filter your list by type using IEnumerable<B> onlyB = lists.OfType<B>();

Comment: So the inner lists, will all the objects stored in the inner list all be guaranteed to be the same type?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I don't think I understand your question. All objects in `List<A>` are of type `A`, all objects in `List<B>` are of type `B`, etc.

Comment: Yes, but You don't have a `List<A>` or a `List<B>` You have a `List<object>` that holds A items and a `List<object>` that holds `B` items with both lists held inside a `List<List<object>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I know to do it is build up a new collection, as you build it up see if you see any known types in the class. If you do see a known type put it it just before the first sighting or put it at the end if no known types were found. Once you have that collection just enumerate the collection in reverse order and it will the items in reverse dependency order.

The below example is used like

```
var sortedLists = lists.OrderByTypeDependency();
```

How to implement the LINQ style extension method:

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> OrderByTypeDependency<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        LinkedList<T> knownItems = new LinkedList<T>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var itemType = item.GetType();
            var itemPropertyTypes =
                itemType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .Select(x => x.PropertyType);
            var itemFieldTypes =
                itemType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .Select(x => x.FieldType);

            //Create a set of all types internal to type we are checking on.
            HashSet<Type> itemChildTypes = new HashSet<Type>(itemPropertyTypes.Concat(itemFieldTypes));

            bool found = false;
            for (var knownItemNode = knownItems.First; knownItemNode != null; knownItemNode = knownItemNode.Next)
            {
                var knownItemType = knownItemNode.Value.GetType();
                if (itemType == knownItemType || itemChildTypes.Contains(knownItemType))
                {
                    knownItems.AddBefore(knownItemNode, item);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
            {
                knownItems.AddLast(item);
            }
        }

        //output the result in reverse order.
        for (var knownItemNode = knownItems.Last; knownItemNode != null; knownItemNode = knownItemNode.Previous)
        {
            yield return knownItemNode.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: it was not clear if you where passing in a list of types or a list of objects. If you are passing in a list of types it is only a few small tweaks to the code, just drop the two `.GetType()` calls and switch from generics to only accepting `IEnumerable<Type>`

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> OrderByTypeDependency(this IEnumerable<Type> items)
    {
        LinkedList<Type> knownItems = new LinkedList<Type>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var itemType = item;
            var itemPropertyTypes =
                itemType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .Select(x => x.PropertyType);
            var itemFieldTypes =
                itemType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .Select(x => x.FieldType);

            //Create a set of all types internal to type we are checking on.
            HashSet<Type> itemChildTypes = new HashSet<Type>(itemPropertyTypes.Concat(itemFieldTypes));

            bool found = false;
            for (var knownItemNode = knownItems.First; knownItemNode != null; knownItemNode = knownItemNode.Next)
            {
                var knownItemType = knownItemNode.Value;
                if (itemType == knownItemType || itemChildTypes.Contains(knownItemType))
                {
                    knownItems.AddBefore(knownItemNode, item);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
            {
                knownItems.AddLast(item);
            }
        }
        for (var knownItemNode = knownItems.Last; knownItemNode != null; knownItemNode = knownItemNode.Previous)
        {
            yield return knownItemNode.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Per your update to the question, as long as the inner lists hold the same type of object in the list so we can just check the first item in the list to find it's type this modification of the original code will do the sorting you need.

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> OrderByTypeDependency<T>(this IEnumerable<T> outerList)
        where T: IList
    {
        LinkedList<T> knownItems = new LinkedList<T>();

        foreach (var innerList in outerList)
        {
            if(innerList.Count == 0)
                continue;
            var itemType = innerList[0].GetType();
            var itemPropertyTypes = itemType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .Select(x => x.PropertyType);
            var itemFieldTypes = itemType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .Select(x => x.FieldType);

            //Create a set of all types internal to type we are checking on.
            HashSet<Type> itemChildTypes = new HashSet<Type>(itemPropertyTypes.Concat(itemFieldTypes));

            bool found = false;
            for (var knownItemNode = knownItems.First; knownItemNode != null; knownItemNode = knownItemNode.Next)
            {
                var knownItemType = knownItemNode.Value[0].GetType();
                if (itemType == knownItemType || itemChildTypes.Contains(knownItemType))
                {
                    knownItems.AddBefore(knownItemNode, innerList);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
            {
                knownItems.AddLast(innerList);
            }
        }
        for (var knownItemNode = knownItems.Last; knownItemNode != null; knownItemNode = knownItemNode.Previous)
        {
            yield return knownItemNode.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted as this helped me find some possible solutions. Please see my edit however as the solution you are proposing didn't quite work for me and I suspect it's because I didn't specify enough.

Comment: @Mat please update your question with a full example with `List<List<object>>` and use A, B, and a C that all depend on the next to show a complete example of a before sorting and a after sorting. Make something that we could just copy and paste in to https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and see what you are trying.

Comment: @Mat See my update that works with a `List<List<object>>`

Comment: I really appreciate the work you've put in this elaborate answer, but I found my own solution just now and it's much shorter; now, should I simply post it, or do something else ?? As for an executable example, it's not so easy to come up with one since I don't know what's being understood and what isn't. For me, the OP edit right now shows what it needs to show.

Comment: I think I see the problem here, my next edit will probably change a lot, sorry for that. Give me a minute.

Comment: @Mat feel free to answer your own question and accept the answer.

Comment: After testing a few solutions, and tweaking some, I found out that your last update is roughly equivalent to what I found to be best, minus some specific details of my code. You got the accepted answer. :)